# Selenium click is not triggering the javascript function on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, selenium

Here is the HTML code

```
<table class="table-main ">
  <thead>
  <tbody>
       <!---->
     <tr class="" ng-if="mapCtrl.isAdded" style="">
        <td/>
        <td>
        <td>
        <td>
        <td class="table-close-btn">
           <i class="form-check tick-mark" ng-mousedown="mapCtrl.createTable()"/>
           <i class="form-close" ng-click="mapCtrl.cancelTable()"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <tr ng-mousedown="mapCtrl.createTable()" ng-if="mapCtrl.showEmpty">
    <!---->
    <!---->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Please check the bold line  `*<i class="form-check tick-mark" ng-mousedown="mapCtrl.createTable()"/>.*` I have tried to click the element through selenium with following ways but none of them work on chrome:

1. Selenium default .click() by identifing the element with xpath and css. `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("i[ng-mousedown='mapCtrl.createTable()']")).click();`
2. Selenium Action class by `moveToElement(el).click();`
3. Java Script Executor with `js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", el);`  and `js.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML", el)`;  and

   JavascriptLibrary jsLib = new JavascriptLibrary();
                                   jsLib.callEmbeddedSelenium(driver,"triggerMouseEventAt", el,"click", "0,0");

No of the function helped to click the element. Can anybody help regarding this?

Please feel free if you need to know anything else.

Comment: Can you consider to indent the HTML as per the actual please? Thanks

Comment: Does it work on Firefox? If not, the click is probably executed before the listener is set by angular. Try to wait before the click to see if it's the case. Be also aware that a Javascript `.click()` doesn't emit the mouse events. So make sure you use the Selenium `.click()`.

Comment: @FlorentB. It is working fine on Firefox. I tried with 5secs of sleep still it didnot work on Chrome

Comment: @DebanjanB: Hi Debanjan, I have made the changes. Please check

Answer (score -1):

Try using the selector path to this element:

```
<td class="table-close-btn">
<i class="form-check tick-mark" ng-mousedown="mapCtrl.createTable()"/>
```

Like this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElementBy(By.cssSelector("td.table-close-btn > i.form-check.tick-mark"));
element.click();
```