# Triggering Javascript Event Selenium Click Function

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

new to HTML & Selenium.

I am having some issues running Javascript stored in a  tag using the driver.execute_script() method.

I am attempting to locate the HTML object by XPATH, store it in a Variable "LeaseID," then click the object from there.   [This is a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45438941/selenium-click-is-not-triggering-the-javascript-function-on-chrome)

The HTML for the table in which the object is stored looks like this:

```
    <table class="dataList" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 100%">
        <script language="Javascript">
                        var calcSum = 0;

                        function calc(a){
                            calcSum = calcSum + a;
                        }
                    </script>
                    
                    
                        <script>
                            calc(1129.39);
                        </script>
        <tbody>
            <tr valign="top" bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
            <td class="cell" style="width: 10%; text-align: center;"><u><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript:window.open('/eng/leases/LeaseDetail.do command=loadDetail&amp;leaseSeq=674106&amp;countryId=US&amp;siteId=873818&amp;isDeed=false', 'leases', 'width=780px,height=450px,menubar=no,directories=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,top=100,left=100');">159062</a>
</u>
</td>
                            
                <td class="cell" style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">XXX</td>
            <td class="cell" style="width: 15%; text-align: center;">XXX, LLC</td>
                <td class="cell" style="width: 10%; text-align: center;"></td>
        <td class="cell" style="width: 17%; text-align: center;">XXX</td>
        <td class="cell" style="width: 6%; text-align: center;">OH</td>
                <td class="cell" style="width: 11%; text-align: center;">Feb 28 2047</td>
            <td class="cell" style="width: 11%; text-align: center;">Feb 28 2047</td>
            <td class="cell" style="width: 10%; text-align: right;"><u><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript:window.open('/eng/XXX/payments.do?command=loadPayments&amp;siteId=873818&amp;pepTrackerId=XXX&amp;leaseId=159062', 'payments', 'width=780px,height=450px,menubar=no,directories=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,top=100,left=100');">1129.39</a></u></td>
                        </tr>
                    
                </tbody>
</table>
```

Below is my Python code, I run into a JavascriptException stating LeaseID is not defined - have I messed up my XPATH reference?

I feel like I am missing something simple & would appreciate a second pair of eyes

```
#Selenium imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options



# Adds driver.quit method, sets up driver & defines location
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach",True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
YYY = "https://www.YYYY.com/eng/YYY/search.do?command=loadSearch"

# Navigate to YYY
driver.get(YYY)

#Set value to query YYY by user input
print("Please provide Site ID to Query YYY: ")
BUN = input()

#Finds Site ID field, Inputs Site ID specified by user, then clicks "Generate List" button
driver.find_element(By.NAME,"searchSiteId").send_keys(BUN)

GenerateList = driver.find_element(By.ID,"searchButtonTop")

GenerateList.click()

#Finds & clicks into Lease Info Tab, then clicks into ""

LeaseInfo = driver.find_element(By.ID,"tabTabYYIY_tabView1_5")

LeaseInfo.click()

*#Finds Lease ID Data field & clicks, running inline JS function

LeaseID = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//table[@class='dataList']//tr[1]//td[1]")

driver.execute_script("LeaseID.click();")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** :

The correct usage in your code should be :

```
LeaseID = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//table[@class='dataList']//tr[1]//td[1]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", LeaseID)
```

From the code snippet shared, it looks like your usage of the js script and the execute_script is incorrect.

So, "LeaseID" is a variable pointing to a WebElement present on the page's DOM and that element's context is known only to the WebDriver APIs and not the browser. In order to execute any javascript on a webelement found using the webdriver APIs, you'll need to use the `arguments` array that is used by webdriver APIs to substitute the WebElement/arguments in the javascript.

Given the locator is correct, this snippet should allow you to successfully click on the locator. An even better approach would be to use a mouse event with the bubbles property set to true. Like :

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {'bubbles' : true}));", LeaseID);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm having issues understanding using Webdrivers & this explanation helped a lot. Would you mind explaining why is using the mouse event you describe is preferable to the .click() method?

Comment: Sure, so the `MouseEvent` object is a browser native event which is part of the W3C specification. We're using it as it allows us to use the bubbles property which allows our mouse click to propagate through the DOM tree of that element. Consider it as a more closer simulation of a user click.